# how to get checkbox values using php codeigniter in Controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to PHP codeigniter,

how to get checkbox values using php Codeigniter in Controller.

Here is the Checkboxes, i want to get checkbox values base on name as "businessType" in controller using post menthod.

```
<input type="checkbox"name="businessType" value="1">
<input type="checkbox"name="businessType" value="2">
<input type="checkbox"name="businessType" value="3">
```

Please suggest

thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="businessType[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="businessType[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="businessType[]" value="3">
```

do `$data = $this->input->post('businessType');`

You should see that $data is an array, and shows different values. Try doing `var_dump($data);` to see what's inside the array.

[var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Answer (score 9):

Put braces after each name. Give each a unique value:

```
<input type="radio" name="businessType[]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="businessType[]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="businessType[]" value="3">
```

Get them like this:

```
substr(implode(', ', $this->input->post('businessType')), 0)
```

Answer (score 7):

If only one of these checkboxes can be selected at a time, you should use a group of radio buttons (`type="radio"`) instead.  I assume this is what you are trying to do since the `name`s of all of the inputs are the same.

To get the value of the checkbox or radio button group, use:

```
$this->input->post('businessType')
```

Edit:

If you are actually wanting checkboxes, you will need to name them all something different:

```
<input type="checkbox"name="businessType1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox"name="businessType2" value="2">
<input type="checkbox"name="businessType3" value="3">
```

And then use the same post method as before:

```
$this->input->post('businessType1') //the first checkbox's value
$this->input->post('businessType2') //the second
$this->input->post('businessType3') //the third
```

Comment: but with the help of this how will i get multiple selection values?

Comment: Ah, if you do actually want to get multiple values, you will need to have a different name for each checkbox.  See above.

Comment: this method will make it pretty difficult to work with checkboxes that are dynamically generated. Why not use method suggested by @tpae ?

Answer (score -1):

As dvcolgan (+1) suggested, radio buttons are what you should use, here is an example wrapped in a fieldset.

**Your HTML**

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Choose Business Type:</legend><br>
<input type="radio" name="businessType" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="businessType" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="businessType" value="3">
</fieldset>
```

**Then in your php**

```
$businessType = $this->input->post("businessType");
```

Comment: but with the help of this how will i get multiple selection values?